# Generate multiple plots from generic code in R

Tags: r, ggplot2

I have a piece of code that is used to generate multiple plots from a dataset. The dataset is filtered based on the parameters required of the visualization and is plotted using `ggplot`.

```
library(ggplot2)
summary <- filter(dataframe) 
plot <- ggplot(summary)
```

Now, I have multiple chunks of code for filtering each type of graph and each chunk has a 'summary' and 'plot'.

Is there a way I can plot multiple functions called 'plot' simultaneously? And is there a way to create a userinterface/button that when clicked will generate all the plots in one go?

Comment: Create a list of "summaries" and use a functional, say `lapply` to plot?

Comment: Caveat. You did not create a function named "plot". Furthermore there is already a generic function named "plot" and you would NOT want to overwrite it. And there is a generic function named `summary` so calling the result of a filter call "summary" is a path to rampant confusion.

Answer (score 1):

If each plot is the same *type* of plot but with different data you could write it once an as @Victor Ordu suggests put them in a list using a loop or something like `lapply` or `map()` in the `purrr` package.

You could then arrange them using `ggarrange` from the [`ggpubr` package](http://www.sthda.com/english/articles/24-ggpubr-publication-ready-plots/81-ggplot2-easy-way-to-mix-multiple-graphs-on-the-same-page/).

For example:

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggpubr)

# Plot function
example_plot <- function(x){
  ggplot(x, aes(drat, wt)) +
    geom_point()
}

# Summarise in a dataframe and plot into a list
graphs <- mtcars %>% 
  group_by(cyl) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(graph = map(data, ~ example_plot(.x))) %>% 
  pull(graph)

# Plot them all!
ggarrange(graphs[[1]], graphs[[2]], graphs[[3]], ncol = 3)
```

[image]

Otherwise just skip straight to arranging them.